Azure DevOps Python Script
I have a python script which i want to run as and when anything is committed to code. So when I update information in the repo (say a CSV document) it will run the pipeline which then kicks off the python script. This all works as expected but... the python script then needs to write some files back to the repo.
Is there a way to write this directly back to the repository?

To set up an Azure DevOps pipeline that triggers a Python script on code commits and writes back to the repository. You can create a new project in your ADO, create a new repo or under your existing repo add Python Script and Requirements.
import pandas as pd

# to read CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')


df['new_column'] = df['existing_column'] * 2

# Write the changes back to the CSV
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


create a CSV file (data.csv) to test and a requirements.txt file for adding any dependencies like pandas and create an azure-pipelines.yml file in your repo.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true

- script: |
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    python your_script.py
  displayName: 'Run Python script'

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "abc@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "arko"
    git add data.csv
    git commit -m "Automated commit from pipeline"
    git push
  displayName: 'Commit changes to repo'
  env:
    GIT_AUTH: $(System.AccessToken)


Commit and push your changes
Run the pipeline. Before this ensure that your ADO and GitHub are synced either using OAuth or PAT. Any changes committed to the repo will trigger the pipeline and execute your script and commit any changes back to the repository.


Similar thread
